# kdb: avoid escaping double quotation mark in string

Tags: kdb

I have a JSON string literal as below, needing many backslashes.

```
"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Is there a way to avoid writing these backslashes? For example in Python we can use single quotation marks to delimit a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you store the literal as a dict and convert to json at runtime? That way it remains clean and easier to read:

```
q)jstr:.j.j`key1`key2!("value1";"value2")
q)jstr~"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
1b
```

To answer your question - no, there's no way to avoid escaping in strings other than casting from some other form or running a lambda to generate the string. The built-in function `.Q.s1` could help but I don't think an approach using that would be any better than the `.j.j` approach above

```
q).Q.s1"abc"
"\"abc\""
```